# how to store csv in mongodb using mongoengine in Python 3

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, mongoengine

Need equivalent code in Python 3 with mongoengine 0.10.6 for following

NOTE : CustomFile.file is FileField(mongoengine)

```
buffer = StringIO()

data_frame.to_csv(buffer, index=False, header=header)
buffer.seek(0)

file = CustomFile()
file.content_type = 'text/csv'
file.name = name
file.size = buffer.len
file.file = buffer
```

This does not work after Python upgrade to 3
How to store CSV using FileField in mongo using Python 3?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "doesn't work"

Comment: file doesn't get saved in mongodb, this is happening because there are changes in StringIO in python 3